# How to hook a tool to multiple hook points in Cherrypy?

Tags: cherrypy

I have a custom tool that I have hooked to before_finalize hook point. I want the same tool to run for 'after_error_response' hook point. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is how I am creating my tool

```
class MyTool(cherrypy.Tool):
    def __init__(self):
        cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self, 'before_finalize',
                               self._do_something,
                               priority=100)

cherrypy.tools.mytool = MyTool()
```

Comment: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_cptools.py#L152

Comment: Try redefining `_setup()`

Comment: @webKnjaZ Thanks. Tried that and it worked. Just overloaded the _setup method and called cherrypy.serving.request.hooks.attach('after_error_response', self._do_something, priority=100) from there. Also made sure to call super.

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize the hook point and assign it under different names.

```
cherrypy.tools.mytool = MyTool('before_finalize')
cherrypy.tools.mytool2 = MyTool('after_error_response')
```

To register an identical tool at mutiple points, you'll have to override the `Tool._setup` itself.  Replacing:

```
cherrypy.serving.request.hooks.attach(self._point, self.callable,
                                          priority=p, **conf)
```

with calls for each point.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question. I don't want to have two different tools. Basically when I do cherrypy.tools.mytool.on: True, I want it the tool to be active for both 'before_finalize' and 'after_error_response'